# Finding a root mod $81$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm facing a hard question from a test. answer for it is $47$ with not further explanation.
Question is:

> Find $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/81\mathbb{Z}$ so that $x^{31} = 2 \pmod{81}$.

my ideas so far are that Euler function of 81 is 54.
orders of element in $\mathbb{Z}/81\mathbb{Z}$ are from $\{3,9,27,81\}$
i know i can probably take my time and /^2 the equation
and go over all numbers that are $(81,n)=1$ and use Euler thereom.
to try and solve 
$$
x^{62} = 4 \pmod{81} \implies x^{54} x^8 = 4 \pmod{81}
$$
however this question is 5 point. so i think there is probably a much more faster way to solve it that im missing.
thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  Here, you can use LaTeX to typeset math: see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Since $2$ is invertible modulo $81$ (equivalently, $\gcd(2, 81)=1$), so is $x$.

You know that if $x$ is invertible modulo $n$, then $x^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.

Now the idea is that $\gcd(31, \varphi(81)) = 1$. By Bezout, you can find $a, b$ such that $a \cdot 31 + \varphi(81) \cdot b = 1$.

Then compute
$$
x = x^{1} = x^{31 \cdot a + \varphi(81) \cdot b} \pmod{81}.
$$